# features available for linkedIn API integration

Tags: api, rest, linkedin-api

I am trying to figure what are the features available in standard and enterprise edition of linkedIn API.
Can any one provide the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "enterprise" edition of LinkedIn.  All of the standard API calls are documented on https://developer.linkedin.com and anything else you might want access to would require to you enter into a partner program with LinkedIn.

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

Comment: That partner link doesnt exist anymore